# How to get a list of all the available plugins names

Tags: plugins, api

I want to retrieve all the plugins information in my .NET application. I can get any plugin information by using this API:

> https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/{slug}.json

Now I need to get the names of all the available plugins.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you can use 'query_plugins' - https://dd32.id.au/projects/wordpressorg-plugin-information-api-docs/

Comment: @WebElaine. I have gone through it, but I am unable to get any help from it. Can you please give some real example (API/url) which give me the list of plugin names in json or xml format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this URL to run GET request:

```
https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/?action=query_plugins&request[page]=2&request[per_page]=100&request[browse]=new
```

You will get JSON object that includes plugins, the total number of plugins, page, the total number of pages. It will sort plugins from newest to oldest.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is really helpful, but one problem is that it returns the same result of Page=1 with the following different parameters as well.

e.g

https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/?action=query_plugins&page=3&per_page=50

https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/?action=query_plugins&page=3&per_page=25

https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/?action=query_plugins&page=9

In short page and per_page params doesn't effect the results. Am I doing something wrong and how can I get the results from page = 2,3... and so on?

Comment: I have updated my response, it looks like the format has changed a bit. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can easily go through each page now. One last request, can you please share a link for documentations where different options/params information for this APIs are mentioned. 
I have found this one but it is vague
https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API

Comment: It is similar to theme params on that API page, there is no other documentation.